# Show taxonomy term for administrators only in node creation form

Tags: 8, forms

I have a content type Topic. The topic has the taxonomy terms -health -fitness and -news. I only want certain roles like administrators to be able to see and use the taxonomy term - news when creating topics. I need all other users to only see and use the other two.

How do I go about this? Would hook form alter be the right direction?

Comment: DO you want to access taxonomy term field only for the admin or specific list of terms in field?

Comment: Hi, I want only the people of a certain role (admin or another) to be able to create content and select the News check box/radio button taxonomy term field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and alter the options values based on role.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
/**
 * implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function chad_form_node_topic_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
    if (!in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
      // You can uset values like below.          
      unset($form['topic_types']['widget']['#options'][3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am having problems figuring out the code. The code I am using is below where Chad is the custom module and node_topic is the form. News is the taxonomy term of type topic and I am not sure how to refer to the correct TAXONOMY_FIELD

Comment: `function chad_form_node_topic_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
     $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
     $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
     if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
       // You can uset values like below.          
       unset($form['news']['widget'][0]['state']['#options']['TID']);
     }
 
 }`

Comment: What is the field machine name of taxonomy term you are using in  `node_topic`?

Comment: topic_types is the main vocabulary with term name : News (term tid 3)

really appreciating your help. This is driving me mad

Comment: Updated answer. Hope this heps!

Comment: Still not quite working,doubble checked to make sure the terms are correct [tid] => 3,[vid] => topic_types ,[name] => News
So nearly there.  Does is matter that is it of [#type] => radios ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. After widget, I have given state which is not applicable in your case. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks . it was 
unset($form['field_topic_type']['widget']['#options'][3]);
All working now. Really appreciate your time to help me.

Comment: Ok. If above is working just accept that.

Comment: Is it possible to have another role (as well as administrator) view the field ?

Comment: yes just use `    if (!in_array('administrator', $roles) && in_array('ABC', $roles)) {`

Answer (score 0):

**If you like to hide the whole field**, you probably are looking for the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

**If you like to hide certain terms only**, you could use Views as reference method and filter your terms accordingly:

1. Create a new view for your taxonomy terms.
2. Create a Filter criteria "Term ID" to filter out all terms that shouldn't be available to non-privileged users, add a "Entity reference" display to that view and configure its Term name in the format settings.
3. Implement [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.5.x) in a custom module and remove the filter criteria, if the users have the elevated roles:

**mymodule.module:**

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter()
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() != 'my_taxonomy_reference_view') {
    return;
  }

  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();

  if (in_array('USER_ROLE', $roles)) {
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions']['key_of_condition']);
  }
}
```

4. Head to your taxonomy term field settings and choose your view as reference type.

You might have to fiddle a little with the conditions, as the above example is just an outline for how you could do it. I actually didn't try it myself. But it should get you going.

Comment: Field permissions deals with the permission and visibility of the whole field. I am looking to show the field but hide one of the taxonomy terms that can be selected.

Comment: I see. Obviously I got your question wrong.

Comment: @GregHalford See my updated answer. It hopefully is of help.